# Source code for a simple website with 5 pages

Tags: html

I have a friend who is in desperate need of help with a website and has to have it done tomorrow. I have knowledge of C# and some basic python, but am new to HTML. I know this isn't necessarily a question involving help with my own code, but how would I go about making a website that is just 5 links to other parts of the site, a header, and body text in each. If anybody could let me know it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is going to get downvoted & flagged unfortunately. I want to help, but please provide any code that you have - we offer assistance more in the form of troubleshooting / bug fixing than recommendations / free software building :)

Comment: Do you know of any place that I could find a quick solution for this? I have almost no code, having almost no knowledge of html. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at my answer, and please bear in mind, we're happy to help, but we need code examples. Have a go at creating the pages by yourself, and then post the **code** so we can help you better debug/fix whatever is broken. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create `HTML` files (the simplest way is in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/), save them as a `.html` extension
2. Read this [Basic HTML Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp) to help you get the structure.
3. Read this [Basic HTML Linking Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)
4. If you want to style your page, read up on `Css` with this [Basic HTML + CSS Tutorial](https://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/applyingcss/)

Basically, each `HTML` page will be of the structure:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<a href="../myotherhtmlfile.html">A link to a HTML file in the same folder</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Goodluck! Please read the content of the links I've provided!

AND, once you have content, post more questions with bugs you have & we'll endeavour to help you solve them as quickly as possible.

Comment: thank you much! really appreciate it. I'm gonna do my best with this. Is it possible to link to a page if i'm not hosting the website on a domain, ex running the code on an emulator of sorts? It's his website, I don't have access to a host

Comment: Yeah, should be. I'd start with just linking pages in a folder though, see how you go with that? When you get up to that stage maybe post another question & we'll attempt to assist.. be sure to give **as many details** and **as much code** as possible though to get a swift resolution :)

Comment: Ok, cool. So when I link a local file would I just use href?

Comment: Yup, have a read of the linking example, but you can link to a specific file using `href`. You'll need to get the link correct i.e. the `../thisismyfile.html` part (where the `/` are the number of folders deep etc. But just have a crack and see how you go

Comment: You are outstanding. I really appreciate your help, I know it's a pain just helping me from scratch. If there's any way to make it up to you I'd gladly do it! I'll comment when i revise the original with some code.

Comment: That might be an option, however if you're pretty far through & you have a tonne of code, I'd recommend making a new question - as you're more likely to get a response on a new question (as the way it pops up on the feed) and I have no guarantee I'll be around later tonight! Goodluck! Just bear that in mind!

Comment: Just an update for you since you pointed me in the right direction, I now know what to do in order to complete this website for my friend. Thank you so much!